# something wrong on my two radio inputs in js and php

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is part of my PHP and JS. These two radio inputs are on my contact form and after I added "domain" radio input, it stopped sending emails to me.
It was working fine until "transfer" radio input. I'm trying to figure out what am I missing.

thanks

---

```php
if(isset( $_POST['transfer'])){
    $transfer = $_POST['transfer'];
}
if(isset( $_POST['domain'])){
    $domain = $_POST['domain'];
}
```

---

```js
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Sending...";
formData = {
    'transfer'  : $('input:radio[name=transfer]:checked').val()
    'domain'  : $('input:radio[name=domain]:checked').val()             
};
```

---

```html
<form>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="transfer"><span style="color: #000">transfer</span></label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <label class="form-check-label active" for="transfer1"><span style="color: #67615e">yes</span></label>
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="transfer" id="transfer1" value="yes" checked="">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="transfer2"><span style="color: #67615e">no</span></label>
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="transfer" id="transfer2" value="no">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="transfer3"><span style="color: #67615e">no clue</span></label>
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="transfer" id="transfer3" value="no clue">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="domain"><span style="color: #000">domain</span></label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <label class="form-check-label active" for="domain1"><span style="color: #67615e">yes</span></label>
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="domain" id="domain1" value="yes" checked="">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="domain2"><span style="color: #67615e">no</span></label>
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="domain" id="domain2" value="no">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="domain3"><span style="color: #67615e">no clue</span></label>
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="domain" id="domain3" value="no clue">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please be more specific than *"it stopped working"*. What stopped? What errors? Take a few minutes to help us help you by reading [ask]

Comment: don't you need a comma here?  formData = {
    'transfer'  : $('input:radio[name=transfer]:checked').val()  ,
    'domain'  : $('input:radio[name=domain]:checked').val()             
};

Comment: sorry about that charlietfl. i didn't make myself clear enough so i edit my post. thanks

Comment: DCR omg thats right. im missing a comma there. thanks for your sharp eye. let me try to fix that and see if it goes through

Comment: it goes through -_-; silly mistake there :X thanks for your comments. helped me alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you lack "," in json format, it should like this

```
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Sending...";
formData = {
    'transfer'  : $('input:radio[name=transfer]:checked').val(),
    'domain'  : $('input:radio[name=domain]:checked').val()             
};
```

Try to add ","

```
 'transfer'  : $('input:radio[name=transfer]:checked').val(),
```

Hope it's help

Comment: share my experience when working with javascript, jquery. I usually use firebug (plugin on Firefox) or firebug feature of chrome for debug and determine where is going wrong